# Backup file attributes / restore them later

Tags: backup, permissions, restore

Currently I am trying to imagine a way of backing up all the file attributes and permissions of a certain directory, i.e. /volatile, for later restore. The procedere I have in mind would be:

- backing up all the file attributes in /volatile
- update /volatile (cloned from a git repo)
- restore the file attributes to the new files

File attributes which should be preserved are for example, ownership and access rights as well as setuid-bits, etc ...

How would I do that if the file and directory structure is always completly identical and how would I do that if there are minor changes (i.e. one file deleted).

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which filesystem (FAT/NTFS/ext3...)?

Comment: filesystem is ext3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will restore Unix file permissions, POSIX ACLs, and (if `setfacl` run as root) file ownership:

```
getfacl -R /volatile > /backup/acls
```

```
cd / && setfacl --restore /backup/acls
```

This will restore ext3/XFS extended attributes (xattrs):

```
getfattr -Rd /volatile > /backup/xattrs
```

```
cd / && setfattr --restore /backup/xattrs
```